# How do I add timestamp when publishing UWP in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, signing

I want to add a SHA256 timestamp when I publish my UWP project in Visual Studio. In the manifest designer, I can only pick a certificate, no mention of timestamp anywhere. Furthermore, using SignTool is not possible for appx files, they can only be timestamped upon signing and not afterwards.

I researched this and it seems that if I want to pass the smartscreen properly, my appxbundle should not only be signed with a proper certificate (which does work properly) but also with a proper timestamp.

I looked up that I can make my appx files by hand using MakeAppx.exe but one should expect that it should be possible in Visual Studio...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appxbundle's can only be signed at the time of signing. This is not built into Visual Studio at this moment.

Timestamping is not required to pass the smartscreen filter.